# Opening Instagram Image from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, instagram, nsurl

The code seems to pick up the right variable, but never opens the Instagram App to display that image.

```
func showOriginWebPage() {

    println("showOriginWebPage: \(self.id!)")

    if let appURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://media?id=\(self.id)") {
        let canOpen = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appURL)
    }
}

// println: showOriginWebPage: 932481051119413840_1563069185
```

thanks for any pointers.

[image]

Comment: Thinking about this. What I really what to do is have instagram go to it's page for a specific image in the App. I'm not sure this is possible. Lots of links, digging through the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it

```
@IBAction func openOnInstagramAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://user?id=" + "1234567890" )
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramURL!)
    }else {
        println("Instagram not installed")
    }
}
```